# Parallel alternative to subprocess.run() in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to execute a command in a more efficient way than just using a for loop.

I have the following code which I'm currently running within a for loop, that I'd like to make faster by using all available CPUs:

```py
__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
for file in glob.glob('0*.dck'):
    subprocess.run([r"C:\TRNSYS18\Exe\TrnEXE64.exe",'\\'.join([__location__, file]),"/h"])
```

I've seen quite a few posts but I'm not having much success (this level coding is not my area of expertise)

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Kind regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the file you are opening is a single-threaded application, you can just run it in parallel using python's [ThreadPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool), which by default creates as many threads as the threads your CPU can support, ie: if your CPU is 4C/8T it will spawn 8 threads.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import glob
import subprocess
import os

__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    generator = ([r"C:\TRNSYS18\Exe\TrnEXE64.exe",'\\'.join([__location__, file]),"/h"] for file in glob.glob('0*.dck'))
    pool.map(subprocess.run,generator)
```

Comment: Multiprocessing is better suited to this kind of activity

Comment: @OldBill calling a subprocess drops the GIL, so threads are more suited for this, no need for the extra 20 MBs that will be taken by each of the 8 or so python interpreters, and multiprocessing will run slower due to the overhead from creating each worker.

Comment: You are quite right. I didn't read the question thoroughly enough